# Strange, isolated errors "$compile:tpload"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We're having strange, sporadic JavaScript error messages in our production log files (JavaScript errors are logged in the backend):

Uncaught Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$compile/tpload?p0=modules%2Fsome%2valid-directive-path.tpl.html

The error occurs only with directives. I'm not able to reproduce the errors locally. The templateUrl for the directives are all valid.

The only possible scenario that came to my mind was if the user presses the cancel/stop button in the browser while the page is loading (then i'm able to reproduce the error).

Does anyone have another idea or explanation? Or even a solution :-)

Cheers
Michael

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this problem. I see this problem a lot in my production logs though I have never reproduced it. The upgrade to angular 1.3 seems to have made it much worse.

Comment: Hi Julian! I just answered my own question below ;-)

Comment: I found out that putting an HTML comment inside template html file will throw this error also

Answer (score 1):

We resolved the issue like this:

Since we are caching our HTML templates with $templateCache using the grunt ngTemplate plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates) we do not have the above issues anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like an interesting option. Not sure it will work for us though since a lot of our templates are razor partials and need to be rendered server side at runtime. I think I will try to inline whatever I can though.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest I was able to recreate this issue. By adding logging to angular I established that when the template load fails it does so with a status of 0 which made me think that the request was actually cancelled. This theory was backed up by the fact that we see no server side errors.

If I emulate a device that cannot support html5 routing and then add an arbitrary query string to the end of the route, it causes an infinite digest loop and in the end the whole page reloads a few times. This in turn was causing the outstanding template requests to be cancelled leading to exactly the errors I was seeing in the logs.

So, for me at least, this is really nothing to do with the loading of the templates, it's just an angular bug (which hopefully is going to be fixed in angular 1.3.8)

Comment: This link explained some of the occurrences of this problem that I was seeing: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14219  However, I added a client-side check to discard these errors rather than logging them when the page is being unloaded (and hence XHR requests cancelled). I am still seeing a significant number of the errors though, so there is something else still at play. Driving me bananas. (Am on Angular 1.5.11 at present.)